# “Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 “Invalid value around character 0.“” when use String converted from Date()

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization, date-conversion

I've got an error when I use a String converted from Date() then try to make a request using as parameter.

First try:

```
var currentMonthToContactTime: String? {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM"
        return formatter.string(from: Date())
    }
```

Second try:

```
let currentMonth = String(Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date()))
```

So, when I use a simple String like "11", the request works.

I'm using

```
URLSession.shared.task
```

and

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [.allowFragments])
```

Any tip about this?

Comment: Can you print your responseData bytes? I can't replicate your issue

Comment: IMO you are doing a string interpolation somewhere in your code that you are not showing to us

Comment: Change your `currentMonthToContactTime`type to non optional `String` and it will probably work

Comment: Hi there! I found the error. When I request sending the current month as parameter the response of the API was None. Now I treat this behavior them and worked fine. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

For some requests, the API returned "None" and I not treat them.

After the treament for "None" response the requests works fine.

Thanks for support.